# Ignoring the case for maxDist in stringdist::extract

Tags: r, stringdist

I am using the `stringdist` package in `R`.

For several options:

```
grab(x, pattern, maxDist = Inf, value = FALSE, ...)

grabl(x, pattern, maxDist = Inf, ...)

extract(x, pattern, maxDist = Inf, ...)
```

it uses `maxDist`. This option however counts the distance between `A` and `a` as one. Just as the  distance between `A` and `b`. I would like ignore the letter case, for `maxDist`. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tolower` and write your pattern in lowercase to ignore case:

```r
x <- "Abc"
stringdist::extract(x, pattern = "abd", maxDist = 1)
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] NA
stringdist::extract(tolower(x), pattern = "abd", maxDist = 1)
#>      [,1] 
#> [1,] "abc"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>